# having a constant decrease of a number when pushing a button in C#

Tags: c#, numbers

I am a begginer, so make it easy for me. **I want to display an collection of images at in order of their name (0-20) when I press a button**. I managed to do it with a random number (0-20), but if I want to have a decrease from 20 to 19 to 18 and so on, how would I do that?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    //Random r = new Random();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Ole-Jeger\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test_Spill1\Test_Spill1\Pictures\";
        //Heathbar.Image = Image.FromFile(path + r.Next(20).ToString() + ".png");
        Heathbar.Image = Image.FromFile(path + /*what to put here?*/)
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any attempt in your code to do what you're asking.

Comment: Use a variable.  Subtract 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a class member field `ImageNumber` that hold the the number of the current:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const string path = 
        @"C:\Users\Ole-Jeger\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test_Spill1\Test_Spill1\Pictures\";

    private const int INT_ImageCount = 20;
    private int ImageNumber = INT_ImageCount;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageNumber > 0)
        {
            ImageNumber -= 1;
            // How about disabling the button?
            if (ImageNumber == 0)
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        /*else
        {
            // Bad boys, Bad boys,
            // whatcha gonna do?
            // whatcha gonna do?
            // whatcha gonna do when the number is nil?

            // Note: if you disabled the button, this shoudln't be a problem
        }*/
        Heathbar.Image = Image.FromFile(path + ImageNumber.ToString() + ".png");
    }
}
```

This code will start at `19.png` and go to `18.png`, `17.png` and so on, until it reaches `0.png`.

The code above doesn't output `20.png` because it decreases the value before using it. So the first iteration it is `20`, then it is decreased to `19`, and then it is used.

I have used a constant named `INT_ImageCount` set to `20`, this reflects the fact that there are 20 images from `0.png` to `19.png`. Tweak the value as needed.

**Note**: if you don't have a `0.png` image you may want to add `1` to the variable when you use it:

```
Heathbar.Image = Image.FromFile(path + (ImageNumber + 1).ToString() + ".png");
```

Doing that, it will go from `20.png` to `1.png`. As an alternative you can change the verification to :

```
if (ImageNumber == 1)
```

This will cause the code to go from `19.png` to `1.png` (change the cosntant to adapt to this, although will the constant no longer represent the number of images, but the value of the last image... you may want to call it `INT_MaxImage` in that case).

---

Points of interest:

1. using `int` in modern CPUs is actually faster because it is either a word o half a word. There is no need for using `byte` in this scenario.
2. I have made the path a constant, in practice you may want to make it a `readonly` field that gets its value from the path of the executable (or read it from configuration or a similar source). But that is another story, and shall be told another time.
3. `Random.Next(n)` will give a number that can be in the reange `[0, n)`, I mean that it is not inclusive for `n`. In other words: The result can be 0, but not `n`. So `Random.Next(20)` will never return `20`.
4. As commented, using `-=` on a byte is `unchecked` by default. So it goes from 0 to 255. using `checked{num -= 1}` will cause it to throw an exception. This is because byte cannot store negative values.
5. You may be interested in preloading your images and have them in an array, so it can switch among them faster, also avoid loading the same image twice.

Comment: Hmm.. seems like edit fighting... I'll stop editing, instead I'll point a few things: 1) you are trying to modify the value of a `const` and 2) you are not using that value otherwise.

Comment: Yup. Yet you are still not using it. That would be `Image.FromFile(path + MaxNumberOfImages.ToString() + ".png");`. Also it is not really the max number of images, how about calling it `ImageNumber` or something along those lines.

Comment: thanks. got it working, but once i hit zero my program crashes

Comment: i added the `if (ImageNumber < 1) throw new exception("Implement logic here!")` and I do not know what to implement.

Comment: the `return` dosnt work when i hit 1 then i get this error "\Test_Spill1\Test_Spill1\Pictures\255.png"

Comment: @Theraot: any idea why?

Comment: if it is possable, i could get it to enable another picture box?

Comment: @Ohunter Ah, that's a good gotcha! what happens is that `-=` for `byte` is `unchecked` by default, so it goes from 0 to 255 without an exception. If you want the exception you wrap the instruction in a `checked` block, like this: `checked{ImageNumber-=1;}`. Of course that is not what we are looking for... what you have to do is check the value *before* attempting to decrease it. It must be done in a way such that it won't try to decrease it pass 0. (Also, you can mitigate this by using `int` instead, but the real solution is to check first decrease second).

Comment: i added the `checked{ImageNumber-=1;}` and it says that the " Den aritmetiske operasjonen resulterte i en overflyt." transelated to "the arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow