# Can't stop a timer in c#

Tags: c#, timer

I want the timer to stop when the ImageNumber is equal to zero.

```
private void Health_Regen_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ImageNumber1 == 0)
        Health_Regen.Enabled = false;
    if (ImageNumber1 < 20)
    {
        ImageNumber1++
        HealthBar.Image = Image.FromFile(path + ImageNumber1.ToString() + ".png");
    }
}
```

If I add a return statement after the first if statement the second if statement is disabled.

Comment: [`Timer.Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: ImageNumber1 will never be equal to 0 since you always increment it

Comment: Put your return statement *inside* the if {} block.

Comment: What kind of timer are you using?  You only showed the handler, not the timer.

Comment: Check the answer in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594245/having-a-constant-decrease-of-a-number-when-pushing-a-button-in-c-sharp and put that into a timer instead.

Comment: How are your `decrementing` your `ImageNumber1` value?

Comment: @BlackBear - It is entirely possible that other `events` are occurring simultaneously to the `Timer Tick event` which decrement the value of `ImageNumber1`.  Unfortunately the OP has failed to provide us with the required specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the timer to stop when the ImageNumber is equal to zero.

You appear to already know how to do this, assuming `Health_Regen` is a `Timer` then:

```
Health_Regen.Enabled = false;
```

Will disable your `Timer`.

> If I add a return statement after the first if statement the second if statement is disabled.

That is to be expected as you are using the `return` keyword which will prevent anything after it within the same code block from being executed.

Your question does not make exactly what you are asking clear, however, I am assuming from your comment that the second if statement is not executed that you want to update the `HealthBar.Image` value even if the `Timer` is disabled?  If so then something like below should work for you

```
private void Health_Regen_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ImageNumber1 == 0)
    {
        Health_Regen.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (ImageNumber1 <= 20)
    {
        ImageNumber1 += 1;
    }
    HealthBar.Image = Image.FromFile(path + ImageNumber1.ToString() + ".png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call the **Stop** method on the timer instance.

```
if (ImageNumber == 0)
{
    Health_Regen.Stop();
}
```

Comment: +0: While good suggestion it is not going to help Ohunter as `Enabled=false` achieves about the same and already present in the code.

Comment: all i get when i replace it with this is "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: ok i forgot the "()", but when i reach 0 it hopps up to 1 and i have to go down to 0 again

Comment: What do you mean "when I reach 0"? Like @BlackBear mentioned, nothing in your code seems able to ever decrement your ImageNumber back to 0..

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess!.

Replace

```
if (ImageNumber1 == 0)
```

with

```
if (ImageNumber1 >= 20)
```

Your timer will already stop when ImageNumber1 equals 0, but it just never counts down to 0.
Also if you change `ImageNumber1` to 0. It may already be running the timer which will increment it by one and `skip` the stopper, so pretty much the way you have it coded it's based on luck right now.

The luck happens if you change `ImageNumber1` while timer is already running.

Try this:

```
if (ImageNumber1 == 0)
    Health_Regen.Enabled = false;
else if (ImageNumber1 < 20) 
{
    ImageNumber1++;
    HealthBar.Image = Image.FromFile(path + ImageNumber1.ToString() + ".png");
}
```

Still the luck may still happen best you can do is stop the timer outside the timer when you make it `ImageNumber1 = 0;`

**Best Fix:**
Also a better solution is to fix your program to start at `ImageNumber1 = 20` and just keep going down to 0.. when it hits 0 stop the timer.. you shouldn't make it this confusing all you will have to do is rename a few png files in a new order! instead of

1.png now it will be 20.png
2.png now it will be 19.png
and so on and so on..